# how to the current location in a web app

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-maps, dictionary

I'm currently working on a project about social networking, where I have some problems about getting the users' the location.

The project is web based and I need to know the user's location so that I can tell user is there any friends nearby.

I'm using the php with codeIgniter but I cannot find a way to do it.

Is there any way I can get the users' location(I mean coordinates) over the browser?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is, you need to use HTML5 capabilities.

Check this: http://html5demos.com/geo

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [MaxMind](http://www.maxmind.com/app/ip-location) ( PHP Geolocation API) and [JavaScript Geolocation API](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2023-Geocoding-A-User-s-Location-Using-Javascript-s-GeoLocation-API.htm).